# Convertir Consulta de SQL en linq

Tags: linq, sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta, la cual quiero convertir a linq

```
select top 1 * from detalle_pedido
where articuloid = 13555 //este valor lo obtengo de una variable, por ahora lo tengo fijo
order by id_detalle_pedido desc
```

e intentado hacer lo siguiente, pero no me resulta

```
//objArticulo.articuloid = 13555

var UltimoRegistro = _db.Set<detalle_pedido>().OrderByDescending(dp => dp.articuloid == objArticulo.articuloid).FirstOrDefault();
```

que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la siguiente expresión

```
var articuloid = 13555;

var ultimoRegistro = _db.Set<detalle_pedido>()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.id_detalle_pedido)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.articuloid == articuloid);
```

En el lambda del `.OrderByDescending()` seleecionas la propiedad por la cual se va a ordernar.

El lambda del `FirstOrDefault()` corresponde a la condición del `where` en tu query. Significa: *devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla con esta condición*

Comment: Agradecido Bro!